# Can I get a Github access token limited to access a single organization?

Tags: github-api

I need access to a private repository in an organization through the github api.

I use my Personal access token, but it provides access to my private repos which I don't want it to have.

Is it possible to create an access token with access to only one organization, not all my private repositories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Create a separate Github account and add it to the Owners team only on the single Organization you want access to.  Get and use its access token.

The token will also have admin access to the other account, but that may be acceptable for your needs.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't allow the organization to use access controls to control use of the token. If another owner of the organization ever needed to rotate the token, they'd have to remove the old account and create an entirely new user account.

Comment: @awwright good point. It's possible to limit access further by using Personal Access Tokens with repo-only access on the secondary account. The secondary account is really a limited proxy of the org owner for repo-only access and would be managed by the organization owner. Credential rotation is achieved by generating a new Personal Access Token periodically according to prescribed policy. If there are multiple org owners,  the situation is more complicated, but that is out of scope for the question.

Comment: Tip: You can register GitHub accounts using a task-specific Gmail address (with a `+` sign). https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308648?hl=en